# How to begin with Semantic UI

Tags: laravel, semantic-ui

I'm trying to get Semantic UI to work with Laravel. I downloaded all the files I need, and placed it here : resources/semantic-ui/

Then I called the files in my view like this :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

But it doesn't seem to work : everything displays as I didn't put any CSS at all. I searched for a solution, but couldn't find it. I can't understand what's wrong. Can you help me please ?

Thanks

Comment: So you have those files in your laravel folder right>?

Comment: Yes I do. The answer ViKas Katariya down here works, but I don't really understand it : I don't get why my files didn't work (my view did got the files : I checked in the source code to make sure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This**

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: That works thanks ! But I can't understand what was wrong. Was it my files ? I downloaded them twice to make sure that it wasn't that

Comment: You did place them in `resources/semantic-ui/` but they should have been in `public/semantic-ui/` if you do not compile them using `laravel-mix` or similar. From the browser you only have access to the `public/` directory, no other one.

Comment: You're right, it's because it should've been in public directory !

Answer (score 2):

So you have to get the files from your local folder . 
You have to use `asset` method to get those files working.
Example :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.css')}}">

<script src="{{asset('semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.js'}}"></script>
```

You can use these methods in order to get the files from particular folder in `laravel`.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful because I kind of want to access the file from my project :)

Comment: @ElodieG.Please be careful while using the previous answer . It will affect if you change the development to production . Using `asset` is the best option .